# Quickest way to check if minion passed by pillar exists

Tags: python, salt-stack

I have an orchestration state that takes minion's name via pillar.
What is the quickest way to determine:

- pillar value passed represents a valid minion/s
- get minion's fqdn

So far, I can only think of test.ping, but if the minion IS valid but offline, the return takes a while. There must be a better, quicker way.

I used pydsl renderer. This is what I do for now:

```
...
minion = __salt__.pillar.get('minion')
valid_minion = __salt__['saltutil.runner']('salt.execute', arg=[minion,'test.ping'])

state("state1")
state("state2")
...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any reason you're mixing different styles with `.pillar.get` and `['saltutil.runner']`?

Comment: No reason, I am still learning. Any suggestions? That's the only way I figured out how to run a module.function ON the master against minions so I could store return in a variable for further processing

Comment: I see what you mean. I should be consistent and use: valid_minion = ____salt____.saltutil.runner('test.ping', arg=[minion,'test.ping'])

Comment: Actually, the recommended syntax is the other one - `__salt__["pillar.get"]()` (or in this instance, `__pillar__.get("minion")` and `__pillar__["minion"]` will work)

Comment: Thanks a lot @OrangeDog. I'll try find documentation for this as I am swimming in unchartered seas, specially with pydsl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`manage` runners](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/runners/all/salt.runners.manage.html) are probably best for this.

To test if a minion id is known (and whether it's up), use `manage.status` with `tgt=minion`

Comment: I never knew about this. Thanks so much. This actually works quite well!